# How to split string with two or more separators

Tags: ruby

I have a string that's `'30.04/2012'`, and I want to split it so the output is `['30', '04', '2012']`. That's essentially `x.split('.') and x.split('/')`. How can I do this efficiently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a regex with alternatives.

```
x.split(/[.\/]/)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x = "30.04/2012"
x.scan /\d+/ # => ["30", "04", "2012"]
```